# SOAP body has another xml and it has apostrophe

Tags: xml, soap, apostrophe

we are sending the xml in SOAP body so we have replaced the xml tag with `<`, `>` into `&lt;` & `&gt;` Everything was fine till we encounter an apostrophe.

This XML went through fine :

`&lt;ScemaLocation:Name _FirstName='John' _LastName='OBarber' /&gt;`

But this one threw an error since it has apostrophe in the lastname:

`&lt;ScemaLocation:Name _FirstName='John' _LastName='O'Barber' /&gt;`

We tried all the below option but nothing was helpful

- `O'Barber` => `O&apos;Barber`
- `O'Barber` => `O/'Barber`
- `O'Barber` => `O<![CDATA[']]>Barber`
- `O'Barber` => `O&lt;![CDATA[']]&gt;Barber`
- `O'Barber` => `<![CDATA[O'Barber]]>`
- `O'Barber` => `O&lt;CDATA[O'Barber]]&gt;`
- `O'Barber` => `O&#39;Barber`

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Escape the apostrophe or wrap it in a CDATA section.  Those are your only choices.

Answer (score 0):

We got two option to fix this issue

Option 1: ScemaLocation:Name _FirstName='John' _LastName='O&apos;Barber';
Option 2: We put the entire inner xml in the CData section. So there is not need to replace the < with < and we can use the regular escape sequence for ' as ' so in our case O'Barber

Hope this might usefull to other. Thanks!